# Adjective for something that allows you to be productive

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm trying to describe a programming language. It's a language that's been designed by its creators to allow us, as the developers (users of the language) to be productive.

I have a feeling the following is bad grammar...

> C# is a productive language

... as I feel that's humanising the language? I.e. the language cannot be productive - but the effect it has on the developer is to make them productive.

Is there a suitable adjective I can use instead?

Comment: That's a perfectly fine use of *productive*. Common, too.

Comment: I disagree. A language is a tool. It is not productive of anything. You might as well say, 'This hammer/screwdriver is productive.'  WRT the actual question, I can think of many adjectives but I hate advertising jargon so much that I can't bring myself to suggest them. Probably the most realistic word is 'useful'.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK [And the Internet disagrees right back](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=productive+language&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cproductive%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bproductive%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BProductive%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BProductive%20Language%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I agree with your comment. But, as a programmer I wan't even have noticed any expression error in this text: " C# is more productive in that it takes less time to implement new functionality than it does in C++.  There are a few reasons for this increased productivity: ...". But, taking into account your remark, I will try not to use the word *productive* for a tool.

Comment: If you said "C# is productive" instead, it might sound better, because it's implicit that you mean [Programming in]C# is productive."

Comment: You may use **C# is a language improving productivity** or "productivity-enhancing language".

Comment: If you want to say that the language allows you to write code quickly and easily that expresses complex tasks, you could say it's economical, but then someone might think the licensing is cheap.

Comment: @DanBron "The internet disagrees right back?  Maybe "right" isn't the right word.  The first few pages of your Ngram result reveals that "productive language" is a term of art in the study of natural language acquisition.  It means expression (as opposed to comprehension).  Nothing to do with worker productivity.  Given the word's other meanings and use in medicine and linguistics, I'd say it was advisable to avoid its metaphorical usage here to mean "gives rise to productivity."  As always, YMMV.

Comment: @deadrat Ok, then let's calibrate by "[*productive tool*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=productive+language%2C+productive+tool&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproductive%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproductive%20tool%3B%2Cc0)", which has been similarly disparaged in these comments. Similar level of acceptance to *productive language*. So it's not just MM that has V'd; the language has evolved. Words mean what people has them to mean.

Comment: @DanBron The OP started out asking whether the usage is "bad grammar," but this isn't a matter of grammar, and I don't think it has anything to do with language evolution.  The metaphorical transfer of an adjective from result to the means doesn't strike me as unusual. .  The OP is wrestling with an issue of style, unsuitability, which he speculates might arise from an inapt literal interpretation.  I think he's on the right track about unsuitability but for the reasons I mentioned.

Comment: @deadrat I never mentioned or even thought about grammaticality. Use is licensed by prior use, whether that's at the orthographic, rhematic, syntactic, or semantic level. With evidence of sufficient prior usage, we don't even have to analyze which level we're operating at: because we know it's something people say, and therefore will understand.

Comment: I think the point is that using productive as an adjective with an abstract noun is acceptable. You can refer to a productive method, a productive approach, a productive strategy, etc. I do understand why the OP is not happy with it though, it seems like there's a better word somewhere.

Comment: @DanBron In my comment, "OP" stands for "Original Poster," not "Dan Bron." The OP is uncomfortable with "productive language," and he should be.  But not for the reasons he worries about.  As barbecue says, "there's a better word somewhere."

Comment: It's a very "usable" language. Productive could mean that it's easy to learn (you're quickly producing working code) or that it has capabilities that allow advanced programmers to write both elegant and useful code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an alternative to productive, you could use *efficient*.

Unfortunately, efficiency can have more than one meaning when talking about languages, as it can refer to how many resources the compiled programs need, or how fast they run, but context can make this clear.

Comment: Absolutely. It's an adjective I had considered, but then rejected for the same reason... I'd have all the C/C++/ASM developers screaming "C# isn't efficient!", when in fact we mean it's more efficient for developing in.

Comment: Theoretically, higher level languages are more productive than lower level ones, so you could say it's high level, but then there's COBOL...

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***facilitate***:

> The C<sup>#</sup> language *facilitates* programming.

The word conveys that the language helps makes programming easier.

> : to make (something) easier : to help cause (something)
>   : to help (something) run more smoothly and effectively
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facilitate)</sub>

If you want to emphasize productivity:

> The C<sup>#</sup> language *facilitates* programmer productivity.

Answer (score 0):

**advantageous** –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=advantageous&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> involving or creating favorable circumstances that increase the chances of success or effectiveness; beneficial.
>
> > C# is an *advantageous* language.